# I want to convert my HTML site into iPhone or Droid compatible site. How can I do that?

Tags: iphone, android

My website is really very simple HTML based site. My site is located here: http://www.threesite.com

How can I convert this simple HTML site compatible with iPhone or Droid? Do I need to convert the same into PHP based site and then convert? Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[5 Ways to Create or Convert into Mobile Phone Website](http://www.tothepc.com/archives/5-ways-to-create-or-convert-into-mobile-phone-website/).

The easiest way is to use Google's tool, because it converts your existing site automatically. I've [tried it on your site](http://www.google.com/gwt/x?u=http://thesite.com&btnGo=Go&source=wax&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) and it looks nice.

If you want to tailor the site yourself, you have two options: Building an app or rewriting HTML. A site app makes your site highly customizable and professionally-looking, but it requires a lot of effort and separate development for each platform (iPhone, Android, Blackberry, Symbian, ...), and. it requires your users to specifically download your app.

If you choose to convert the existing HTML to a mobile-friendly site, it will be (mostly) cross-platform, and you can follow the guidelines [here](http://www.mobilehtml5.com/post/371921120/tutorial-your-first-mobile-html5-app-the-basics).

Answer (score 0):

This is very interesting question especially these days when mobile visibility has never been more important. 
For more complex website I would use some online mobile site converter service, such as duda mobile or bmobilized.
These services will give you just mobile - 'm' version of a website, but with long bad urls, and unless you pay for responsive package, the site won't work on tablets.

Maybe the best solution is to use joomla or word press and pick some responsive template and build the website from scratch. Building one responsive site is better solution than having multiple instances for each device...

examples:

a) duda service 
If you wander what duda can do for you, just as an example, check this site [crazyscarygames.com](http://www.crazyscarygames.com) and check out his 'm' counterpart "m.crazyscarygames" for mobile devices. this is just an example.

b) script

If you would go for full responsive site, this is an example of purity III template on this website [monkeygamesworld.com](http://www.monkeygamesworld.com) ... m.monkeygamesworld.com

And remember, always do all redirects from htaccess.

There's a google tool that you can use in the end to verify how your site works on android

google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly

just enter url and hit 'analyze'

also make sure that your robots.txt is setup well, in order to allow google bot do its scan properly throughout necessary directory structure in order to access all resources.

ok, hope that helps